# Python expect date time value

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to fetch the current date using date time object as below:

```
datetime.datetime.today()
```

And this returns value of `2020-06-07 20:55:21.143081`

I however am expecting an output of  `2020-06-07 00:00:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
dt = date.today()
print(datetime.combine(dt, datetime.min.time()))
```

Output:

```
2020-06-09 00:00:00
```